# Cómo hacer para que no se borren mis datos en un arreglo estructurado en c++

Tags: c++, array, estructuras

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para la escuela sobre arreglos y estructuras .

```
struct CD{
int codigo;
char artista[30];
char album[30];
int no_canciones;
float precio;
int existencias;
}CDs[50];

void Menu()
{
    int opc;

    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"--------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout << " 1.  Agregar CD" << endl;
    cout << " 2.  Mostrar todos los CD" << endl;
    cout << "Opcion: ";
    cin >> opc;

    switch(opc)
    {
        case 1: Agregar();
        break;

        case 2: Mostrar();
        break;

    }
}

void Agregar()
{
        system("cls");

        cout << "Cuantos discos desea agregar: ";
        cin >> a;
        system("cls");


        for( i=0; i<a; i++){
            cout << "Ingrese el codigo del Disco " << i+1 << " : ";
            cin >> CDs[i].codigo;
            cin.ignore();
            cout << "Ingrese el nombre del Disco " << i+1 << " : ";
            cin.getline(CDs[i].album,30);
            cout << "Ingrese el nombre del Artista " << i+1 << " : ";
            cin.getline(CDs[i].artista,30);
            cout << "Numero de Canciones en el Disco " << i+1 << " : ";
            cin >> CDs[i].no_canciones;
            cout << "Precio del disco " << i+1 <<" : ";
            cin >> CDs[i].precio;
            cout << "Discos en existencia del disco "<<i+1<<": ";
            cin >> CDs[i].existencias;
            system("cls");
    }
}
```

Todo va bien pero a la hora de ejecutar mi programa le pido al usuario digitar cuantos elementos desea agregar al arreglo.

Se agregan pero si el usuario quiere agregar mas elementos, los elementos que estaban en el arreglo anteriormente se borran

Entonces a la hora de mostrar los elementos de dicho arreglo solo me aparecen los ultimos registrados

Comment: si se reinicia cada vez que agregas, es por que creas la variable al llamar a la funcion. Deberías probar fuera de esta, tampoco veo que estes llamando el valor anterior.

Comment: Cada vez que entras en Agregar, lo que añades lo añades desde la posición 0 hasta el número introducido. Así que claro que estás borrando los anteriores. Es más, si entras una vez y metes 3, y entras otra y metes 2, al salir tendrás los dos últimos los primeros y el 3 de la primera vez. Tienes que guardar el número de elementos que llevas y meter los nuevos a continuación.